# Why does a binary search have a time complexity of O(log n), when the actual time complexity is a step function?

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search

This is the definition of the logarithmic time complexity one normally comes across:

> Logarithmic running time `O(log n)`  essentially means that the running time grows in proportion to the logarithm of the input size.

But in some cases, it doesn't seem that the time grows **strictly** in proportion to the logarithm of the input size. For example, consider binary search. It is said that the algorithm has time complexity of `O(log n)` . I've generated arrays with size ranging from 2 to 1000, and for each array I've calculated the number of iterations (i.e., array splits) in the worst case scenario. This is the result

[image]

Evidently, the actual time complexity is not `log2(n)` (both functions have the same output `x` only if `log2(x)` is an integer).

**So my question is, why are we saying that the binary search algorithm has a `O(log n)` complexity, when the time complexity is in fact a step function?** (the derivation that starts with `1 = N/2^x` and after some algebraic manipulation ends up with `x = log2(N)` doesn't explain the reason)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in your observations. However, big-O is asymptotic notation. In general, when discussing time complexity, we are not interested in a function that gives us an exact number of operations, but we are interested in how the time grows as a function of the input size - specifically, for [sufficiently large](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SufficientlyLarge.html) input sizes.

If you take a moment to understand the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big-O, you will find some interesting properties. One such property is that *O(f(n)) = O(c * f(n) + d)*, where *c > 0* and *d* are constants (if *f(n)* is not constant).

Let us take the step function *s(x)* from your example. We know that for any *x*, *log(x) - 1 <= s(x) <= log(x)*. We recognise that *-1* is a constant, so it follows that *O(s(x)) = O(log(x))*.

Comment: You should also specify `d >= 0`, otherwise you would allow O(1) = O(1 + (-1)) which isn't true. And you would still allow O(0) = O(0 + 1) which also isn't true, so probably best to just forget about the "+ d" part.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you yes, the constant case *f(n) = c* is more involved. I omitted it for brevity, since we are talking about *logn* here. I will edit to your satisfaction :)